# Generate PDF from another page with JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013, jspdf

I have a button in my page to generate PDF I use JSPDF to perform the task, my problem is that I have to retrieve the content in other pages ... I retrieve the html in string format and I do not Know how to handle it....

any ideas
Thank you

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var inner_content1;
var page_title = "ExternalPage";

$.ajax({
        url: "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/sites/site/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + page_title +"'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.d.results[0]) {
                inner_content1 = data.d.results [0].HtmlContenu;
                str = "<div id='someID'>" + inner_content1 + "<div/>";
                //alert(inner_content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)&#160;/ig,""));
                        html = $.parseHTML( str ),
                        nodeNames = [];
                        //var $newDiv = $("<div/>")   // creates a div element
                        //.attr("id", "someID");  // adds the id
                        //$(html).append($newDiv);
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    var specialElementHandlers = {
                    '#someID': function (element, renderer) {
                        return true;
                                        }   
                                };

                        $('#cmd').click(function () {   
                        doc.fromHTML($("#someID").get(0), 15, 15, {
                        'width': 170,
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                                });
                        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
                                                    });

                            });
            }

        },
       error: function(){ //Error }
   }});
     });
```

Comment: When you say another page, do you mean a SharePoint list or library? Then you could add a webpart to your page, and have that list/library printed.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah It is fields of pages (Pages properties) SP pages library

Comment: There could be two approaches to this: (A) Insert your HTML & Javascript through a content editor web part on the library page, (B) Add a new web Part on your page that points to the pages library.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah Approach B I did not understand, for approach A I would no longer need ajax? Because the user has to choose specific fields and I have to fetch in all the pages of the library to find the content and export to PDF

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question completely. Do you wish to export ALL pages from your library to PDF?

Comment: @Nisarg Shah Yes and It depends on the fields that user chooses, can be 2 fields in page A and 1 field in page C  OR maybe 3 fields in the same page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151197/discussion-between-nisarg-shah-and-faxelf).